# Help with Salesforce API getting values from web service (VS C#)

Tags: apex, api, class

I found an API to update fields in VS C# from Salesforce. But I can not figure out a way to request values from the web service(GetVendorService) and store them in a list, so I can display the values in VF page. Please I need help, I know I am pretty close, but this is so new for me.

Let me explain , there are 3 web services, 1. GetWarehouseName 2. UpdateWarehouseName, 3, GetVendorDetails. I have an object Warehouse__c, so if I update a record in salesforce it will update the SQL database through the APIs(GetWarehouseName and UpdateWarehouseName) that is working fine. But Now I need to bring data from VS. I am using the GetVendorDetails web service for now. I need help building the WebServiceCallout.invoke

```
public class MWSFISContr2{

     Public String response {get;set;}
     public String debugSoql {
        get { return response; }
        set;
      }


     public String endpoint_x = 'http://warehouseupdate.domain.com/Service.asmx';
     private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://warehouseupdate.domain.com/', 'WarehouseUpdateService'};


    //button
    public void RequestValues(){

    GetVendorDetails();

    }

     public class GetVendorDetails_element {
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://warehouseupdate.domain.com/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{};
    }

   public String GetVendorDetails() {
            WarehouseUpdateService.GetVendorDetails_element request_x = new WarehouseUpdateService.GetVendorDetails_element();
            WarehouseUpdateService.GetVendorDetailsResponse_element response_x;
            Map<String,String, WarehouseUpdateService.GetVendorDetailsResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String,String , WarehouseUpdateService.GetVendorDetailsResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'http://warehouseupdate.domain.com/GetVendorDetails',
              'http://warehouseupdate.domain.com/',
              'GetVendorDetails',
              'http://warehouseupdate.domain.com/',
              'GetVendorDetailsResponse',
              'WarehouseUpdateService.GetVendorDetailsResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            response=response_x.GetVendorDetailsResult;
            system.debug(response_x.GetVendorDetailsResult);
            return response_x.GetVendorDetailsResult;

        }

    }
```

Here is the Webservice request and response:

```
POST /Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: warehouseupdate.domain.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://warehouseupdate.domain.com/GetVendorDetails"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetVendorDetails xmlns="http://warehouseupdate.domain.com/" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetVendorDetailsResponse xmlns="http://warehouseupdate.domain.com/">
      <GetVendorDetailsResult>
        <Vendor>
          <VendorName>string</VendorName>
          <VendorNo>string</VendorNo>
          <VendorId>string</VendorId>
        </Vendor>
        <Vendor>
          <VendorName>string</VendorName>
          <VendorNo>string</VendorNo>
          <VendorId>string</VendorId>
        </Vendor>
      </GetVendorDetailsResult>
    </GetVendorDetailsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And I need to bring this values from the Webservice(GetVendorDetails) they are all string

```
<ArrayOfVendor xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://warehouseupdate.domain.com/">
<Vendor>
<VendorName>Toshiba</VendorName>
<VendorNo>1042</VendorNo>
<VendorId>3158</VendorId>
</Vendor>
</ArrayOfVendor>
```

Comment: Does the VS C# web service have a method that you can call which returns the values you're after? Once that's confirmed, you can parse the response using XML Reader and put the values in your list to be displayed on your VF page. `http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_xml_streaming_reading.htm`

Comment: Bachovski, thank you for formating my question. Yes VS returns HelloWorld, but I am not able to get any values from salesforce

Comment: this is the return <string>Hello World</string>

Comment: How is this webservice callout invoked and what values are you trying to get from salesforce exactly?

Comment: Let me explain you, there are 3 web services, 1. GetWarehouseName 2. UpdateWarehouseName, 3, HelloWorld. I have an object Warehouse__c, so if I update a record in salesforce it will update the sql database through the APIs(GetWarehouseName and UpdateWarehouseName) that is working fine. But Now I need to bring data from VS. I am using the HelloWorld web service for testing, so I keep it simple for now. I don't not if my code is correct for this purpose or where can I add a System.debug() in this class.

Comment: As far as I can see it's working for you at the moment and I believe you are on the right track. Now from my understanding you want to expand the HelloWorld method to retrieve more data rather than just a string right? Are you able to paste the code where this webservice is invoked from in apex too?

Comment: I was able to get the 'Hello world' I am going to modify the question, now I need to get 3 values from a different web service. Please help me here because I am not able to built the  WebServiceCallout.invoke for this one. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Bachovski, thank you again for formatting this question. I really need to solve this, any ideas? thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have the WSDL file from the other webservice? Why don't you just import it and generate the class automatically by following this - https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm ?